# Error: Can't resolve 'TweenMax' while using Angular CLI with ScrollMagic and GSAP

Tags: javascript, angular, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm trying to integrate Scrollmagic plugin with Angular CLI. However, I'm getting this error:

> ./~/ScrollMagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TweenMax' in
>   '/Users/../project/node_modules/ScrollMagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins'

I have installed GSAP and scrollmagic library using npm:

```
npm install gsap
npm install scrollmagic
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js",
        "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/ScrollMagic.min.js",
        "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"
      ],
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TweenMax, TimelineMax } from "gsap";
import * as ScrollMagic from 'ScrollMagic';
import "ScrollMagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js";
import "ScrollMagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-floating-butterfly',
  templateUrl: './floating-butterfly.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./floating-butterfly.component.scss']
})
export class FloatingButterflyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: ".floating-butterfly"
    })
    .setTween(".floating-butterfly", 0.5, {backgroundColor: "green", scale: 2.5}) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
    .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"}) // add indicators (requires plugin)
    .addTo(controller);


  }
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem at the moment... TweenMax is the only plugin that I can't import. TweenLite, TimelineLite & Max, CSSplugins all work. Tried with absolute path imports too, instead of npm package, same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @NicoPrat Please refer the answer by LucitheR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should 'ng eject' your app. That will give you access to Webpack (no you can't go back, so make sure to back up. ).

```
npm install gsap imports-loader scrollmagic --save
```

it's important that you install the imports-loader. when the webpack.config.js is added to your project root, reinstall the app `npm install`, since there are new things that needed to be installed, afterwards put this in your webpack aliases:

```
  "alias": {
"TweenLite": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite.js'),
"TweenMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js'),
"TimelineLite": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js'),
"TimelineMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax.js'),
"ScrollMagic": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js'),
"animation.gsap": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js'),
"debug.addIndicators": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js'),},
```

add this to your Component.ts:

```
import 'imports-loader?define=>false!animation.gsap';
import ScrollMagic from 'ScrollMagic';
import 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators';
import {TweenMax} from 'gsap/TweenMax';
import {TweenLite} from 'gsap/TweenLite';
import {ScrollToPlugin} from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin";
```

that should work

Comment: Thanks, that's working. But now how do I compile the project without using `ng build` command? Is there any equivalent option within webpack?

Comment: @RahulDagli `npm run build` or `npm run start` should work, see package.json in the script section